# Ubuntu: звук + щелчок внутри ноутбука

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Периодически мой ноутбук издаёт странные, на мой взгляд, звуки.

Это началось после того, как я перешёл на Ubuntu (на Windows такого не замечал) ...

---

Иногда внутри ноутбука возникает такой сигнал:

> `пи-и-и-к` → `щелчок` (как-будто что-то переключилось)

Раньше замечал и немного иные сигналы:

> пару раз `пи-и-и-к` в разных тональностях, а затем `щелчок`

Также щелчок воспроизводится при выключении компьютера.

---

Что это может быть: то ли опасаться, то ли нет; — не знаю?

---

- **Ноутбук:** `Samsung NP-RV513-A02UA`.
- **Жёсткий диск:** `SAMSUNG HM321HI (2AJ10002)`.

Comment: Не факт, что связано именно с ОС. Я бы проверил винт по поверхности через MHDD. Ну и контроллер sata должен быть при этом в IDE mode.

Comment: Я тоже "вангую" за жесткий диск. Наверняка, стоит хард Samsung, частенько за ними такое замечал.

Comment: Да, стоит диск `SAMSUNG HM321HI (2AJ10002)`. Я провёл короткую диагностику с помощью Disks (Ubuntu) — она показало, что всё OK. Сейчас провожу расширенную диагностику и написал в Samsung, может они что подскажут.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем, вот что мне ответили в Samsung:

> Такие звуки и щелчок связаны именно с жестким диском. Причина, скорее
>   всего, в том, что Linux не имеет поддержки со стороны Биоса ноутбука и
>   контроллера жестких дисков и поэтому его команды неправильно
>   отрабатываются и щелчок это звук парковки головок не в штатном режиме.
>   Это не очень хорошо и может привести к ускоренному износу механики
>   жесткого диска.  Рекомендуем произвести возврат на предустановленную
>   версию операционной системы.

Начав гуглить по запросу `linux samsung hdd bios`, нарвался на следующую статью:

> [Problem with hard drive clicking](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_hard_drive_clicking)

Там очень много информации по `hard drive clicking` — нужно пробовать; ну и гуглить, если ничего не подойдёт, эту же фразу — информации также достаточно. Однако первым делом в любом случае нужно отловить логи при этом кликаньи, а там уже будет всё понятно, надеюсь.

Comment: чекни `grub` обычно он виноват в межсистемных проблемах с диском. Скорее всего при переустановке не была произведена полная очистка информации с диска, и от того появляються проблемы.